# Adding Modules Directory to @INC

Tags: perl

I have a bunch of scripts that I  need to run them in sequential manner somthing like the below

```
foreach my (qw (script1.pl script2.pl script3.pl ){

 my $script=File::Spec->catfile($Bin,'Scripts',$_);
 system "$^X $script";
}
```

every of those scripts use 2 modules which located under lib library where the scripts found i.e

i have project library which contian the above script and 2 directory one for my modules and the other for the scripts that the above script run,the question how can i add the modules directory to the @INC path in dynamic manner on the above script that when I run the system code it will find the lib directory on the @INC path .I tried to use the following :

```
BEGIN{
use lib File::Spec->catdir($Bin,'LIB');

}
```

but its not works any idea?

The error I get for every script on the loop

```
"BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Porject\Scripts\script1.pl line 4
Can't locate Detection.pm in @INC"
```

Comment: Please provide the complete error message and the full path to the module you are trying to load. (You can replace private information if you need to, just be consistent. e.g. replace your company name with "xxx" and your user name with "yyy" everywhere.)

Comment: Is Detection.pm in "Porject\LIB"?

Comment: Yes if i print File::Spec->catdir($Bin,'LIB') i can see that it on the right directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear WHERE you're manipullating `@INC`, but the way I read your question, it seems you did it in script.pl.

Simply changing `@INC` of parent script **will not** affect `@INC` of scripts you call via `system()` call, since those child scrips will have their own copy of Perl interpreter.

You need to manipulate it in the called scripts (script1.pl, script2.pl, script3.pl).

You can do it 1 of 3 ways:

1. By adding "-I" Perl parameter when calling the script from script.pl:

   ```
   my $lib_path = File::Spec->catdir($Bin,'LIB'); 
   system "$^X -I $lib_path $script";
   ```

   *Benefits*: You only put the code in 1 script (parent one).

   Because of that, this is the solution I would recommend.
2. By having script1.pl (and 2 and 3) adjust its own `@INC` based on script path.

   For example:

   ```
   use Cwd qw(abs_path);
   use FindBin;
   use lib abs_path("$FindBin::Bin/../LIB");
   ```

   *Benefit*: You don't need to know ehere "$Bin" is. *Downside*: you need to edit every one of those scripts.
3. By having script1.pl (and 2 and 3) adjust its own `@INC` based on the logic you tried to put into parent script:

   ```
   # Add to scriptX.pl - all of them.
   BEGIN { use lib File::Spec->catdir($Bin,'LIB'); }
   ```

   *Downside 1:* you need to edit every one of those scripts. *Downside 2:* You need to know where "$Bin" is in every one of those scripts.